# Instrumentation to add logging to Scala code

Tags: scala, logging, bytecode-manipulation, aspect

In Java we can use `AspectJ` to add logging transparently to Java classes (or probably use other byte code instrumentation tools). Now I wonder how to add logging transparently to *Scala* functions.

I would like a tool to transform a function `foo`

```
def foo(x:Int) = x + 1
```

to something like that:

```
def foo(x:Int) = { 
   log.trace("Enter foo with x = " + x) // added automatically
   val r = x + 1
   log.trace("Exit foo with r = " + r) // added automatically  
   r
}
```

How would you add logging transparently to Scala functions?

Comment: You tried AspectJ and had some problems with it? To my knowledge, AspectJ works not only with source, but with bytecode, and Scala compiles to the same bytecode that java does.

Comment: No, I did not try it. You are right AspectJ does work with the byte code but I am afraid it will have difficulties to work with Scala.

Answer (score 2):

AspectJ will work just fine with Scala code. You'll just need to follow the Scala name mangling rules (i.e. `def >` becomes `def $gt`) and so on.

Suppose you have

```
class Foo {
  def foo(x: Int) {
  }
  def bar() { }
}
```

To add logging, you can use the Java AspectJ syntax, adding

```
"org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % "1.7.2",
"org.aspectj" % "aspectjrt" % "1.7.2"
```

To your `build.sbt`. Moving on, you can have the following aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class MonitorAspect {

    @Pointcut(value = "execution (* your.package.Foo.*(..))")
    public void methodsInFoo() {}

    @Before("methodsInFoo()")
    public void enter(JoinPoint jp) {
        // log
    }

    @After("methodsInFoo()")
    public void exit(JoinPoint jp) {
    }
}
```

The final piece will be the `META-INF/aop.xml`, which defines the work for the load-time weaver:

```
<aspectj>

    <aspects>
        <aspect name="your.package.MonitorAspect"/>
    </aspects>

    <weaver options="-XnoInline">
        <include within="your.package.*"/>
    </weaver>

</aspectj>
```

Finally, start your JVM with `-javaagent:$PATH_TO_ASPECTJWEAVER.JAR` and you're all set.

---

In your case, it may be worth thinking about using higher-order functions. If you are using logging as just an example, and if you're actually doing something *before* and *after* some inner function, you should consider using HOFs.

```
def logged[U](f: => U): U = {
    log.info("Before")
    val ret = f
    log.info("After")
    ret
}
```

Here, you have the `logged` function that takes another function `f`, deals with the logs and does whatever `f` does.